# Qt how to get all widgets and their z-index at certain QPoint?

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

As shown as screenshot below, there are 3 widgets overlapped. When user clicked a certain point (eg. the white cross in the example), I want get all widgets at this point. In this example, I want get Widget 1/2/3 and their z-index.

**Is there a simple way to achieve this?**

More details:
I have a <del>Microsoft Visio</del> **Qt Designer** like app developed in Qt, and I want implement a feature as below:

1. When user first clicked the white cross point by mouse left button, the front most widget--Widget 3 will be selected;
2. Then, when user clicked this point again, Widget 3 will be unselected and Widget 2 will be selected;

[image]

Comment: If you're using `QGraphicsScene` you can use one of the [`QGraphicsScene::items`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#items-1) overloads to get a list of items under a specific point.

Comment: Using widgets for this is not the best idea, since you're poorly reimplementing what is already done for you in `QGraphicsScene`.

Comment: Sorry, it's not a Microsoft Visio like app. It's a Qt Designer like app, user can drag and put qt widgets on a canvas to build ui. And it does not use QGraphicsScene but QWidget.